# Only encode specific characters [PowerShell]

Tags: powershell, encoding, character-encoding

Using `[uri]::EscapeDataString($element)` escapes every special character including `/`, but I still need the urls readable for the report a11ym generates. How would I only escape `&` in powershell?

```
# Execute a11y machine

$urls = @(
    "https://url.com/"
    "https://url.com/jobs/intro?_ab_sessid=6f022ebc900f9cd04a6383f8eaab3c64",
    "https://url.com/jobs/intro?_ab_sessid=6f022ebc900f9cd04a6383f8eaab3c64&mobile=false&width=675&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=-300&jun1offset=-240&in_iframe=1",
    "https://url.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchLocation=&searchCategory=&hashed=-435830103"
   )

$encode = foreach ($element in $urls) {
    [uri]::EscapeDataString($element)
}

a11ym -o careers_reports/$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d")/ $encode


a11ym-dashboard --root careers_reports --static-output
```

Comment: The escape char is `
So 
Hey`&Hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to process the escapes you didn't want to happen and put them back in, it appears, if you want to use that class method.

```
([URI]::EscapeDataString($element)) -replace 'REGEXP','&'
```

---

Edit:

```
$element = $element -replace '&','&amp;'
```

Comment: Is there a better method for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: unfortunately, powershell is still failing on the `&` in `&amp`

Comment: I don't think it's PS failing.  Use `& "path\to\a11ym.exe" arg1 args` in your call